# Switched Capacitor Basics

Tags: switched-capacitor

[image]

[Taken from Razavi's Analog IC CMOS Design Book]

My confusion is with the line that says *"Such an arrangement is indeed practical if the circuit senses only high-frequency signals."*

Firstly, I'm a bit confused, what exactly is the purpose of the circuit in 12.2(b)? Is it just to set a bias point?

Secondly, high-freq AC signals will see the capacitor as a short, so what exactly is that going to achieve?

I think I'm just struggling to see the problem with these circuits and thus I can't figure out why certain solutions are needed?

Comment: In my understanding, he is trying to establish a feedback mechanism for the bias voltage. This cannot be achieved with the feedback capacitor, since caps don't pass DC voltage. By installing a high-valued resistor, bias voltage can pass and the parallel total impedance is very close to that w/o the resistor. \$Z_1 // Z_2 \rightarrow Z_2\$ if \$Z_1 >> Z_2\$. In reality, this works better for HF signals since cap impedance becomes very small.

Comment: @thece why does it work better for HF signals? Cap impedance becomes small so you have a unity feedback path for HF signals? I mean even with a low frequency signal, the DC level of the output is still going to bias the input through the feedback resistor right? Just not sure why this is only good for HF.

Comment: Gain depends on the ratio \$\frac{Z_{fb}}{Z_{in}}\$, not on each impedance separately. At HF \$X_{fb}\$ becomes much (much) smaller than \$R_{fb}\$, so the approximation \$X_{fb} // R_{fb} \rightarrow X_{fb}\$ works much better.

Answer (score 0):

None of those circuits are actually *switched capacitor* although these might help in explaining some concepts.

Although it has only capacitors in the signal path, 12a is an amplifier whose frequency response goes all the way down to DC. It does have a basic problem, however: the amplifier bias is not well-defined without additional circuitry. The DC offset from input to output is otherwise arbitrary.

12b is the simplest possible biasing alternative for this circuit. The problem is that it introduces a zero at DC and a pole proportional to 1/R, that  translates into a first- order highpass response. Which means that it blocks DC, only frequencies above the pole will see the same amplification as in 12a.

Answer (score -1):

12a) is for DC to AC charge Amps that need a Cf shunt to reset often used for  gyro or accelerometer to DC.

12b) is for AC since self biased yet BW Limit to 1/Rf*C